# Cofinality of an ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be ordinals.
Is it true that $\mathrm{cf}(\beta)\le \mathrm{cf}(\alpha)$, if there is a function from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ with cofinal image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any ordinals $\alpha,\beta$, if $\alpha>\beta$ then there is a function from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ with cofinal image (why?). Now, can you think of a pair of ordinals $\alpha>\beta$ with $cf(\alpha)<cf(\beta)$?

Comment: Note to the OP: Notice that if you require that the function is strictly increasing, then the answer is true if and only if the cofinalities are equal.

Comment: If $\beta \lt \alpha$ then $\beta \subset \alpha$, so we have surjection from $\alpha$ to $\beta$. And, for example, $\omega +1 \gt \omega$, but $cf(\omega +1)=1 \lt \omega =cf(\omega)$

Comment: @alexivanov right, so what does that tell you about the answer to your question?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, oh, of course, the answer is negative. Thank you.